# Statuses table database design

Tags: sql-server, database

I have four tables listed below:

**Shipments**

- ShipmentID (PK)
- OtherShipmentInfo

**ShipmentStatus**

- StatusID (PK)
- StatusDescription

**ShipmentStages**

- ShipmentStageID (PK)
- ShipmentID (FK to Shipments)
- StatusID (FK to ShipmentStatus)
- DateTime

**DeliveryCodes**

- DeliveryCodeID (PK)
- DeliveryCodeDescription

My question is which table is "more appropriate" to store information relating to the final status of a shipment? If I need to record the delivery code only at the time of the final shipment stage, should I use a foreign key in the `ShipmentStages` table or place the foreign key in the `Shipments` table and only update that foreign key at the time of the final stage?

Because the `DeliveryCode` is only relevant to the final shipment status, if I place the foreign key in the `ShipmentStages` table, a majority of the entries will have NULL values.

I feel either scenario would "work" but which one is "more appropriate"?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have edited the post to only include the appropriate tag.

Comment: Can there be multiple deliveries based on a shipment being incorrect being returned and reshipped? Would that all be attached to the same shipment or would each be a separate item?

Comment: In our model, a shipment can only have one attempted delivery. In the event a delivery could not be made, then a new shipment would be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options:

1. Combine your statuses and delivery codes into a single table.  If a Shipment has a "DeliveryCode" status, it has been delivered.  In essence, the delivered status is replaced with all of the possible delivery codes.  ShipmentStages still only needs a single FK reference to ShipmentStatuses.  DeliveryCode table is removed.
2. Add a N/A or Pending status to your delivery codes table with a FK reference in ShipmentStages.  Any shipment status that has not yet been delivered will use the "not delivered yet" delivery code.
3. Redesign your model to capture the delivery event as a separate entity.  This would require a table referencing the DeliveryCode and Shipmment tables.  This is the most extensible and least likely to require a redesign in the future.

**----Updated for comments----**

Separating Shipment Stages and Delivery does not violate normalization.  Delivery and Shipment Stages both describe Shipment, but Delivery does not describe Shipment Stages.  3NF would likely dictate to put the delivery attributes in the shipment table as they describe the shipment.  The attributes you may capture for a delivery do not describe the shipment stage, they describe one type of shipment stage.  Since that stage has its own unique attributes, it can be broken into a separate entity.

If volume/performance dictate, separating the delivery event attributes into their own table can reduce the CRUD load on the shipment table for delivery specific work.  Another way to consider that is if you primarily use the shipment table without the delivery details and/or the delivery details without the shipment details, there may be gains made by separating them.  You can tightly couple them by having the Delivery table use the Shipment table PK as its own PK (1-[0,1] relationship).

If you do not yet have performance concerns, start out with the delivery code in the Shipments table.  It can always be separated later (though development work will be required).  Premature optimization can sometimes be a waste of time/money.

Comment: If option 3 is used and we go with a separate entity for the actual delivery event, what then happens to the `ShipmentStages` table? A trigger that updates the `ShipmentStages` table upon an entry into the new `Delivery` table? Doesn't that violate a normalized approach?

Comment: I would recommend enforcing the relationship through the front end application or a back end stored procedures.  I am not fond of enforcing relationships through triggers.  I've found them hard to troubleshoot/rewind when something goes wrong.  I've added additional content to my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful response. This has forced me to rethink my model and make changes for the better. I will be moving forward with creating a separate `Delivery` entity as I believe this will be more flexible in the long run. Much appreciated.